# Acess listview data from context menu

Tags: android

I have created a list view with the following data: id name date and i created a context menu my problem is to retreive the name from the item selected in the context menu option. How can i do this:

```
  @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item1:


          return true;
    case R.id.item2:

        return true;
    default:
          return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

my code:

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products =       "http://10.0.2.2/webprojecto4/index_pesagem.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "cab_doc";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "descricao";
private static final String TAG_DATA = "dt_ini_camp";
private static final String TAG_DATA2 = "dt_fim_camp";
private static final String TAG_QTD = "qtd";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    registerForContextMenu(lv);

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String id2 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Linhas_pesagem.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_ID, id2);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });


}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);


                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);                    
                    String data = c.getString(TAG_DATA);
                    String data2 = c.getString(TAG_DATA2);
                    String qtd = c.getString(TAG_QTD);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_DATA, data);
                    map.put(TAG_DATA2, data2);
                   map.put(TAG_QTD, qtd);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_DATA, TAG_DATA2, TAG_QTD},
                        new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.descricao, R.id.data, R.id.data2, R.id.qtd});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item1:




          return true;
    case R.id.item2:

        return true;
    default:
          return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you select on the context menu? Id? Name?

Comment: i want to select the name of the item that activates the context menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `info.position` is the index in the collection of the element that was pressed to invoke the context menu. So `YourObject temp = yourCollection.get(info.position);` will give you the whole object.

EDIT:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
HashMap <String, String> product = productsList.get(info.position);
String name = product.get(TAG_NAME);
//name contians the name of the product, similarly you can get the others
}
```

Comment: i know and how can i get the name of the element

Comment: Depends how you defined your object which contains the id, name, date. If the property is "name" than just a simple temp.name would do it.

Comment: So , you long press some product of the listview and context menu appears?

Comment: I will modify the answer now. And please accept it if it helps you.